# Is it possible to pin a note above all other in Keep?

Tags: google-keep

I use Google Keep daily and I need one of my notes above all others. Is it possible to show it above all my older ones and also make the new ones appear under it (pin it or something like that), so I don't have to move it every time I create a new note?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Keep now allows you to pin notes.

Just hover over the note and click the pin icon on the top.

[image: Pin Google Keep Note]

Comment: Looks like they added in the last couple of days, but I don't see any announcements about it.

Comment: (Not yet available in the Android app.)

Comment: @AʟE. Feature now available on the latest Google Keep update for Android.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recently added feature. Please see [rahi's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/99577/354).

---

Unfortunately, no, there isn't a way to "pin" a note so that it doesn't move.

I see a couple possible alternatives to make it easy to quickly find a single note:

- Change the color of the note to something distinctive. (I hardly ever put color on my notes, so a red one really sticks out.)
- Create a custom label (e.g., "_top") for the note you want to find, and apply it to that note. If you always have the menu open, the label will be at the top and you can reach it with a single click.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer. Will definitely try coloring it since I dont use the colors either.

Answer (score 1):

► A note cannot be 'pinned' to the top in Google Keep

- Text search or filter on colour or label is the most rapid method of note recovery.

► Automatic arrangements:

- New notes placement at top of (current) Notes stack; freshly archived notes go to the top of the archive; unarchived notes go to the top of the (current) Notes stack.
- Devices and zoom will place notes on the screen on a best fit basis

► Manual arrangements:

- Use archive or delete when done. Drag notes on Keep apps on phone, pad, and PC; but not on web page on PC.
- Use Grid view for general layout of notes showing the first c10-20 lines; use list view to show a sequential story.

► Workflow:

- Include a endnote in your favourite note 'MyPin' and search to recover the note.
- Move your favourite note to the top of the (current) Notes stack by archive then unarchive; or by repeatedly dragging it.﻿

Comment: Note: A pinning feature has been added since this answer was written.